# How can I create this spinning wheel effect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to re-create the following spinning-wheel effect in JS. Does anyone know what's used here or how I could achieve it?

https://www.outpan.com/app/ddd2faecf3/random-picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the source of your example, notice the style:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="transform: rotate(3357deg);"></canvas>
```

[Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) in CSS allows you to rotate an element. Apply it dynamically to induce the effect upon user interaction.